# ionic 3 : Failed to display image using camera plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to load an image using camera plugin in an ionic app, but the image is not displayed an no errors ares generated. Here is the typescript code for i use to load the image :

```
import { ImagePicker } from '@ionic-native/image-picker/';

import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {

    public imageUri: string = '';

  constructor(
    public toast: ToastController,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public storage: Storage,
    public platform: Platform,
    public transfer: FileTransfer,
    private camera: Camera,
    public imagePicker: ImagePicker
  ) {

  }

    upload() {


    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      targetWidth: 800,
      correctOrientation: true,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageUri) => {
      this.imageUri = imageUri;
        this.toast.create({
        message: this.imageUri.toString(),
        closeButtonText: "Okay",
        dismissOnPageChange: true,
        showCloseButton: true
      }).present()
    }, (err) => {
      this.toast.create({
        message: err.toString(),
        closeButtonText: "Okay",
        dismissOnPageChange: true,
        showCloseButton: true
      }).present()
    });
 }
```

In the html side, here is how i display the image :

```
 <div class="profile-picture">
    <div class="image">
       <img [src]="imageUri.replace('file://','')" *ngIf="imageUri !== ''">                    
    </div>
    <p (click)="upload()" tappable style="width: 100%;">load  profil picture</p>
  </div>
```

So when the user select an image, it is not displayed in the view. I am using 
**cordova-plugin-ionic-webview   ": "^3.1.2**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.

html:

```
  <img src="{{imgUrl}}" (click)="pickImage()" id="image">
```

ts:

```
public takePicture(sourceType) {
  // Create options for the Camera Dialog
  var options = {
   quality: 100,
   targetWidth: 80,
   targetHeight: 80,
   destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
   sourceType: sourceType,
   correctOrientation: true
 };

// Get the data of an image
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
  this.prepareFile('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imagePath);
}, (err) => {
  this.presentToast('Error while selecting image.');
})};



private prepareFile(namePath) {
 this.imgUrl = namePath;
}
```

sourceType is `this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY` or `http://this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA`

Comment: Hello @Leonid Prokopenko. Thans for your contribution. Your solution  works, but i wanted to display the image whithout converting it to a base64 string. Is it possible

Comment: try the tutorial for handling camera images at https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-images/ i remember it worked fine for me

Comment: Thank you for your contribution but it did not worked for my project. However, I found that it  my code did not work because, to read the image, i have to move the image file to the application directory using the file plugin, and read it from there.